# Understanding a complex docker command

Tags: docker

I was just going through this tutorial online and the author , uses the following command along the way:

> sudo docker run --name my_sql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword --volumes-from my_datastore -d mysql

So my understanding of the above command is as follows there is a specific name given to the image and after that there is a environment variable being passed and after there is a `--volumens-from` command being executed , `-d` indicates that the container should be run in the background .

I am not sure what i mysql is at the end.

My question is as following:

Docker uses the following syntax:

```
docker [OPTIONS] COMMAND [arg...]
```

in the command that i have highlighted what are the `[OPTIONS]` what is the `COMMAND` and what are the `[arg...]` ? also what is mysql doing in the end of the command ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: In this case, the `COMMAND` is `run`, and I know I've recently directed you to the reference for that command, which should help explain the rest of that command line.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and you're correct on your statements.

The naming convention is as follows:

The name of the container

```
--name my_sql
```

Environment Variable(s) - You can add as many as you want, each with an additional '-e' directive

```
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
```

Directive to use a volume from a different container

```
--volumes-from my_datastore
```

Run in the background

```
-d
```

The name of the Docker image that you're using to make a container

```
mysql
```

You could even use something like mysql:latest (the :latest is a tag that would pull the most recent version of that image).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Two things make it hard to understand for newer, let me explain

#### First, what's inside of docker image `mysql`.

There is no Dockerfile in hub.docker.com for image `mysql`. So if you don't understand what is running in container with this image, you can run below command to get details

```
$ alias dfimage='docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm centurylinklabs/dockerfile-from-image'
$ dfimage mysql
ADD file:f7eb3ddd8c7f33332cd94564ec171306ffa490836953449b9b9c506085ec8745 in /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql
RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y perl --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys A4A9406876FCBD3C456770C88C718D3B5072E1F5
ENV MYSQL_MAJOR=5.6
ENV MYSQL_VERSION=5.6.26
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/ wheezy mysql-${MYSQL_MAJOR}" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
RUN {       echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/data-dir select '';      echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/root-pass password '';       echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/re-root-pass password '';        echo mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-test-db select false;     } | debconf-set-selections  && apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server="${MYSQL_VERSION}"* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*     && rm -rf /var/lib/mysql && mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql
RUN sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf   && echo 'skip-host-cache\nskip-name-resolve' | awk '{ print } $1 == "[mysqld]" && c == 0 { c = 1; system("cat") }' /etc/mysql/my.cnf > /tmp/my.cnf  && mv /tmp/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
VOLUME [/var/lib/mysql]
COPY file:eebf5525e2e95ae059f8b5954a592e533f986fd2073741a1e0b7731ff2cb3860 in /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT &{["/entrypoint.sh"]}
EXPOSE 3306/tcp
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

So it exposed port 3306 and run the default command `/entrypoint.sh mysqld` if there is no `--entrypoint` option override it.

Notes:

- you can replace the entrypoint command with `--entrypoint`
- you can run `docker history mysql` to get similar information, but not good enough.

#### Second, how to understand `--volumes-from`

`--volumes-from` is the volume in another container `my_datastore`, you should be fine to use similar dfimage to show its volume:

```
docker inspect -f {{ .Volumes }} my_datastore
```

with `--volumes-from`, the mysql container can access the data in another container.

If you want to know more about `--volumes-from`, go though this document [Managing data in containers](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/)

For the rest options, you should be fine. If you have any question, let me know.